# R ggplot2: Color grouped barplot based on condition / numerical thresholds

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following input for a grouped bar plot that I generate with ggplot2:

```
Disease;Category;Value;pValue
Disease A;Count;100;0.0001
Disease A;Expected Count;50;0.0001
Disease B;Count;80;0.0005
Disease B;Expected Count;40;0.0005
Disease C;Count;60;0.0010
Disease C;Expected Count;40;0.0010
Disease D;Count;45;0.05
Disease D;Expected Count;50;0.05
```

The following code generates the grouped barplot:

```
literature.disease2 <- read.table(file = "/user/literature-disease2.csv",sep=";", header=TRUE)
literature.disease2.sorted <- literature.disease2[order(literature.disease2$pValue,literature.disease2$Category),]
ggplot(data=literature.disease2.sorted, aes(x=Disease, y=Value, fill=Category)) +
geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge(),size=.3, colour="black") +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("Count" = "lightblue", "Expected Count" = "pink")) + # Change color
  xlab("Disease Category") + ylab("Literature Count") + # Set axis labels
  ggtitle("Genome-Wide Literature Counts") +     # Set title
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle =90, hjust = 1,vjust=0.5))
```

This is the plot:
[image]

*Now I would like to color the bars in blue (instead of light blue) and purple (instead of pink) whenever the pValue <= 0.005. I know that I have to change the **scale_fill_manual** option, but I do not know how to do this for grouped bar plots. Can anyone help?*

Thanks in advance, Frank

Comment: This is a good question. However, I think your code is too messy with many unnecessary parts. Try to keep your examples as minimal as possible so that others can understand it more easily.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I should focus on the specific question so that it is easier for others to follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code might get you started, but think about adding significance as, for example, alpha aesthetic instead of double coding.

The key point is using `interaction()` as the `fill` aesthetic and mapping the colors appropriately.

```
library(ggplot2)
literature.disease2 <- read.table(text = "Disease;Category;Value;pValue
Disease A;Count;100;0.0001
Disease A;Expected Count;50;0.0001
Disease B;Count;80;0.0005
Disease B;Expected Count;40;0.0005
Disease C;Count;60;0.0010
Disease C;Expected Count;40;0.0010
Disease D;Count;45;0.05
Disease D;Expected Count;50;0.05",sep=";", header=TRUE)
literature.disease2.sorted <- literature.disease2[order(literature.disease2$pValue,literature.disease2$Category),]
ggplot(data=literature.disease2.sorted, aes(x=Disease, y=Value, fill=interaction(Category, pValue <= .005))) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge(),size=.3, colour="black") +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("Count.FALSE" = "lightblue", "Count.TRUE" = "blue", "Expected Count.FALSE" = "pink", "Expected Count.TRUE" = "purple")) + # Change color
  xlab("Disease Category") + ylab("Literature Count") + # Set axis labels
  ggtitle("Genome-Wide Literature Counts") +     # Set title
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle =90, hjust = 1,vjust=0.5))
```

Here is a plot with my suggestion:

```
ggplot(data=literature.disease2.sorted, aes(x=Disease, y=Value, fill=Category, alpha = pValue <= .005)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge(),size=.3, colour="black") +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("Count" = "blue", "Expected Count" = "purple")) + # Change color
  scale_alpha_discrete(range = c(0.5, 1)) + # Make the "insignificant" bars a little more visible (default range = c(0.1,1))
  xlab("Disease Category") + ylab("Literature Count") + # Set axis labels
  ggtitle("Genome-Wide Literature Counts") +     # Set title
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle =90, hjust = 1,vjust=0.5))
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. The usage of option "interaction()" was the missing piece.